# Multispectral images (Band Sequential format)

Tags: gdal, c++, file-formats, format

How can I create a multispectral image file (in band sequential (BSQ) format), from several 1-band images, using GDAL libraries?

I work with C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

From C++ you can create your output file using [GDALDriver::Create()](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDriver.html#adb7bff9007fa5190d6cf742cf76942a8) to imperatively create your multi-band output file.  Then open each of your input files in turn read the band of image data with [GDALRasterBand::RasterIO()](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a5497e8d29e743ee9177202cb3f61c3c7), and then write it to the appropriate output band in the output file.  This assumes each band isn't too large to hold in RAM.

If you want to copy over a band in chunks you could do it yourself, our you might consider using [GDALRasterBandCopyWholeRaster()](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#aff879725bbdb026dc2bd932dda19a17f) which will do it in reasonable sized chunks with an optional progress monitor.

The gdal_translate program actually accomplishes copies in a much more complicated way where it forms a VRTDataset referencing the source image and then uses CreateCopy() from that, but this complication is mostly just of value if you want to write to a format that does not support GDALDriver::Create() so that you need to use [GDALDriver::CreateCopy()](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDriver.html#a2c897da2a6e25169cccc49ef48797ce1) instead.  For instance many compressed formats.  But if you just want to create a raw BSQ format like ESRI BIL that is not required.